# Proxy with Express.js + Request.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, request

I started writing a proxy server with Express.js and Request.js

The server runs on port 900 and does:

1. Serve static content from path `/prototype`
2. For certain calls
   forward the request to another server (on port 8080)
3. Resolves
   `/prototype/[this|that]` to the corresponding static html
   `/prototype/this.html` and `/prototype/that.html`.
4. Also serve this.html as default for /prototype

I managed to achieve 1) - 3) with following code:

```
var express = require('express'), path = require('path'), request = require('request');

var app = express();

app.get('/prototype', function(req, res, next) {
  // a) request(req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host') + req.url +  '/this').pipe(res);
  // b) res.redirect('/prototype/this');
});

app.get('/prototype/:path(this|that)', function(req, res, next) {
  var resolvedUrl = req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host') + req._parsedUrl.pathname + '.html';
  request(resolvedUrl).pipe(res);
});

app.get('/prototype/sample/:path', function(req, res, next) {
  var resolvedUrl = 'http://localhost:8080' + req.url;
  request(resolvedUrl).pipe(res);
});

app
  .use('/prototype', express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '../')))
  .use(app.router)
  .use(express.errorHandler({
    dumpException: true,
    showStack: true
  }));

module.exports = app;
```

My folder structure is

```
prototype
|_css
| |_<css files>
|_js
| |_<js files>
|_this.html
|_that.html
```

this.html refers to the files in css and in js

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css" />
<script data-main="js/app.js" src="js/require.js"></script>
```

In order to achieve 4) I tried to request the `/prototype/this` path when `/prototype` is requested, however then the js and css are requested from `/js/app.js` and `/css/app.css` instead of `/prototype/js/app.js` and `/prototype/css/app.css` which fails. (See `a)` in the code comment).
The behavior I would like to achieve can be achieved with `b)` but I don't want to have the URL bar in the browser changed to /prototype/this but keep it in `/protoype`.

Any nice way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to be a missing trailing slash.. after `/prototype`.
Without the trailing slash I was overriding the behaviour that redirected to the directory with trailing slash when requesting directory path without trailing slash.

Changed it to the following and it works like a charm.

```
app.get('/prototype/', function(req, res, next) {
  // a) request(req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host') + req.url +  '/this').pipe(res);
  // b) res.redirect('/prototype/this');
});
```

Comment: could you please give advice for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22684644/angularjs-expressjs-proxy-post-request-is-pending I will appreciate it very much :)